# Performance issues with external IO?

Tags: usb, performance

I have an odd situation on my machine. I have multiple external USB 3.0 drives doing high amounts of IO (about 70-100MBps each, copying disk images or using tools like `dd`) but very low IO on my system SSD drive.

I can run a high IO operation on each of these drives fine, but once I'm using 3+ drives my system gets unusably laggy even though my CPU, Memory, and System IO usage is low. I can `ionice` the operations which helps a little but I still run into the same bottleneck.

Where might this bottleneck be?

Specs:

> i7 processor 12GB memory,
>   internal system drive is SSD
>   all externals are USB 3.0 5400-7200RPM,
>   Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

When the bottleneck is hit, RAM usage is <50% swap has <1GB used, system IO is just whatever is required to run Ubuntu not running any heavy operations there, CPU is <30% usage across all cores.

Comment: System specs would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the page cache is being filled up by these large read/write operations, and the page cache is system-wide, not per disk. I posted a similar question at the Unix StackExchange and [got an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474171/303376), which enabled me to skip the cache using the `dd` command...